# Create a query that joins 2 set of data entries in 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My target is to how can I fetch my data looking like they're matched (They will be matched based on their points? (See the 2nd table)

Here in this first table, we can see that these are all the players who are registered.

| id | player | points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | miguel | 1 |
| 2 | law | 1 |
| 3 | paul | 2 |
| 4 | zafina | 2 |
| 5 | ogre | 3 |
| 6 | noctis | 3 |
| 7 | baek | 4 |
| 8 | hwoarang | 4 |

After creating some query, they'll be matched if they have the same points. (See the table below).

| id | player | points | player | points |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | miguel | 1 | law | 1 |  |
| 2 | paul | 2 | zafina | 2 |  |
| 3 | ogre | 3 | noctis | 3 |  |
| 4 | baek | 4 | hwoarang | 4 |  |

This is how i fetch my data from DB

html:

```
 <table id="players" class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0">
                  
                     <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th>id</th>
                           <th>player</th>
                           <th>points</th>
                        </tr>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 
    //datatables
    table = $('#players').DataTable({ 
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'print', 'csv', 'copy', 'excel', 'pdfHtml5'
        ],
       
        "processing": false, 
        "serverSide": true,  mode.    
        "order": [], 
        
 
       
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('controller/function')?>",
             "type": "POST",
             async:true,
             dataType: "json", 
             
         
             "data": function(data){

            },
            
        },
 

 
    });


    });
```

controller:

```
 public function function()
    {
        
        
        $list = $this->model->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $person) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            
            $row[] = $person->id;
            $row[] = $person->player;
            $row[] = $person->points;
        
            
            
            
            
            //add html for action

            
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        
        $output = array(
            "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
            "recordsTotal" => $this->model->count_all(),
            "recordsFiltered" => $this->model->count_filtered(),
            "data" => $data,
        );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

model

```
    var $table = 'players';
    var $column_order = array(null,'id','player','points');
    var $order = array('id' => 'desc');
    var $column_search = array('id','player','points');

    
    private function _get_datatables_query()
    {
      
        $this->db->from($this->table);
  
//         $this->input->post('start'); // YYYY-mm-dd
//         $this->input->post('end'); // YYYY-mm-dd

        
        
    
        
        $i = 0;
        
        foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {
                
                if($i===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                
                if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $i++;
        }
        
        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        }
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }
    
    function get_datatables()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
            $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
    }
    

    
    
    function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
    
    public function count_all()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }
```

Comment: _"After creating some query, they'll be matched if they have the same points"_ - what if they don't? Or is that a given - that there will always be two players with the same points? No single players, not ever three players with the same points? Can there be _four_ with the same points, and if so, how should those get distributed then?

Comment: They'll not be in the same array if they don't have the same points. The only one who can be joined in 1 array are 2 players with the same points.

Comment: If you have free time, please take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70075267/create-a-query-syntax-that-joins-2-set-of-data-with-the-same-points-in-1-row 

This is a better version of this question (I hope you can help me, thank you so much)