# Create a query syntax that joins 2 set of data with the same points in 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My target is to how can I fetch my data looking like they're matched (They will be matched based on their points? (See the 2nd table)

Here in this first table, we can see that these are all the players who are registered.

| id | player | points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | miguel | 1800 |
| 2 | law | 1800 |
| 3 | paul | 1830 |
| 4 | zafina | 1830 |
| 5 | ogre | 1840 |
| 6 | noctis | 1840 |
| 7 | baek | 1850 |
| 8 | hwoarang | 1860 |
| 9 | king | 1900 |

After creating some query, they'll be matched if they have the same points. Hence, if there are more players who haven't found a match, find a match with greater than or less than equal 10 (See the table id 4).

| id | player | points | player | points |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | miguel | 1800 | law | 1800 |  |
| 2 | paul | 1830 | zafina | 1830 |  |
| 3 | ogre | 1840 | noctis | 1840 |  |
| 4 | baek | 1850 | hwoarang | 1860 |  |
| 4 | king | 1900 | match not found | match not found |  |

As we can see on the table above, Baek and Hwoarang got a match. The reason for this is because when there are no more players with the same points, the 2nd query should find a match for a player who has less than or greater than equal 10. But if players exceed the 10 points > or < limit. Then they should be labeled as "no match found"

HTML:

```
<table  class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped is-narrow is-hoverable">
      <thead>
          <tr>
           <th class="bg-danger text-center">id</th>
            <th class="bg-danger text-center">player</th>
            <th class="bg-danger text-center">points</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="playerdisplay">

      </tbody>
  </table>
```

script:

```
  $(document).on('click','#player',function(){
     $.ajax({
         url:"<?=site_url('controller/players')?>",
         method:"POST",
         dataType:'json',
         success:function(data){
             $('#playerdisplay').html(data);
         }
     })
  })
```

Controller:

```
function players(){
  $query=$this->player_model->playerss();
  $a=0;
  $row = '<tr>';
  
  foreach($query as $rows){
      $row .= '><td>'.$rows->player.'</td>;
      $row .= '><td>'.$rows->points.'</td>;
      $row.= '</tr>';
  }

  $row.= '</tr>';
  echo json_encode($row);
}
```

Model:

```
function playerss(){
    $query =$this->db->get('player');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Show us a raw SQL query what you trying to execute

Comment: (1) What is **precise** MySQL version? (2) If John, Jim and Mike have 1800 points and Jane have 1801 points, who must be the pair for Jane and why?

Comment: Mysql 5.7 version.  for the 2nd question, If there are players who have less than or greater than equal 10 points, then jane should be matched on that player. The first requirement is it is should be always the same points, if not, greater or less than equal 10. I'm sorry if i made it confusing. Thank you and have a nice day